# java dom xml parser get html tags(<p color="something">some text</p>) from xml

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have an xml file with html tags like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <blog>
 <blogid>49</blogid>
 <title>[FIXED] Job requests page broken</title> 
 <fulltext>
 <img title="page broken" src="images/west/blog/site-broken.jpg" alt="page broken" />
 <p><span style="background-color: #ccffcc;">Update 28/05/2011</span>: Job requests page seems to be working OK now. If you find any issues please use the contact page to notify us. Thank you for your patience!</p>
<p>Â </p>
 <p>Well, what can I say? Why does it always have to be that way? You are trying to create something new and something else gets broken on the way...</p>
 </fulltext>
```

Now I want the whole html part between  tag as it is.
What I get right now is blank as I think dom is parsing html tags as well.

I tried xpath but it is not working with android.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to parse the XML?

Comment: Do you want the text between the `<p>`s or the entire node?

Comment: Android does support Xpath, depending on the version.. http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Comment: i want the whole html part between <fulltext> tags,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get this not well-formed XML into a DOM as-is. (EDIT: or is it well-formed?)

You would need to a) either escape the characters - making the XML well-formed and parseable (but probably not into a DOM you want, I guess you want to display the HTML in a different system) or b) parse it using a stream processor or c) fix it using string manipulation (add <[[CDATA .. ]]>) and then parse it into a DOM.

HTH

Comment: i tried CDATA which gives me text part,whereas i need tags with attributes like <span style="background-color: #ccffcc;">.
i'll try to look into stream processing.

Comment: With CDATA, you should get a node with all the content inside of fulltext - and no other nodes or attributes inside it. Can you post some sample code?

Comment: also, where did you add the CDATA instruction? and how did you retrieve the content (code sample)?

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a sub-language of XML (without getting into details related to XHTML). Therefore, there is no reason for the DOM parser not to treat those inner tags as XML tags.

Maybe what you're looking for is a way to flatten what's inside `<fulltext>`?

Comment: @jason: then you can traverse the DOM tree to find the `<fulltext>` tag, then convert it to a string. Example: http://www.coderanch.com/t/124119/XML/DOM-string

Comment: Not be be nagging, but HTML isn't really a sub-language of XML. A valid HTML document is not necessarily a valid or even well-formed XML document. XHTML is a language built with XML syntax, HTML on the other hand is more lenient.

Comment: Which is exactly why I've written "(without getting into details related to XHTML)" :)

Answer (score 0):

use a library like Jsoup for this purpose.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String html = "<?xml version="1.0"?><foo>" + 
                  "<bar>Some&nbsp;text &mdash; invalid!</bar></foo>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

    for (Element e : doc.select("bar")) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }   


}
```